# Using Python 3.5, throwing error: TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: python-3.x

I am using Spyder Python IDE, Python version 3.5 and trying to run this python [file](https://github.com/udacity/ud120-projects/blob/master/datasets_questions/explore_enron_data.py) having code

```
import pickle

enron_data = pickle.load(open("../final_project/final_project_dataset.pkl", "r"))
```

However on running, it throws following error

> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to open your file in binary (so `read` it returns `bytes` and not `str`):

```
open("../final_project/final_project_dataset.pkl", "rb")
```

(note the additional `'b'` in the mode).

Comment: Now it complains again: _pickle.UnpicklingError: the STRING opcode argument must be quoted